# dataframe grouping and sorting

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas and have a dataframe,df

```
    Index         prt     Mb      
 2017-08-09       tt      0       
 2017-08-09       uu    140       
 2017-08-10       uu    200      
 2017-08-11       tt     0        
 2017-08-11       tt    150      
 2017-08-16       uu    200
```

I want a dataframe like this

```
   Index          prt    Mb      ttt
 2017-08-10       uu    200     200/1000=0.2 
 2017-08-11       uu    200     200/1000=0.2
 2017-08-09       uu    140     140/1000=0.014                 
 2017-08-11       uu     0      0/10000=0
```

the ttt column should be replaced with the result of the division by 1000.How can I go about it?

Comment: You can try: `df['ttt'] = df['Mb']/ 1000.0`

Comment: this only gives the ttt column and this does not filter the prt column based on uu values

Comment: You can filter and sort by: `df = df.loc[df.prt == 'uu'].sort_values(by='ttt', ascending = False)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt you need groupby here

```
df= df.sort_values('Mb',ascending=False)
df['ttt'] = df['Mb'].div(1000)
# Based on the comment. `df['ttt'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Mb'],errors='coerce').div(1000)`

        Index prt   Mb   ttt
2  2017-08-10  uu  200  0.20
5  2017-08-16  uu  200  0.20
4  2017-08-11  tt  150  0.15
1  2017-08-09  uu  140  0.14
0  2017-08-09  tt    0  0.00
3  2017-08-11  tt    0  0.00
```

To remove the `tt` from the dataframe a simple boolean indexing would be enough i.e

```
df[df['prt'].eq('uu')] 

      Index   prt   Mb   ttt
2  2017-08-10  uu  200  0.20
5  2017-08-16  uu  200  0.20
1  2017-08-09  uu  140  0.14
```

Comment: what if there  are more values in prt column other than uu and tt? how can i remove others

Comment: Change `ne` to `eq('uu')`

Comment: Where's the question

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int' for this line:df['ttt'] = df['Mb'].div(1000)

Comment: The other question might help `df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['Index']).dt.weekday_name).size().to_frame('Count')`.

Comment: And for all futurue references put the df.dtypes output in the question. I thought it was a numeric column.

Comment: You can put the `sort_values` line after `df['ttt'] = ...`. Have a good day

Comment: For the code to the other question  df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['Index']).dt.weekday_name).size‌​().to_frame('Count')‌​.......i got a syntax error:invalid character in identifier

Comment: even putting the sort_values  after the df['ttt'] = .... the values are not sorted

Comment: I need to see the real data that you have. Based on the sample data you gave it works.  I think data is messed up and a bit of cleaning is necessary. Its hard to answer every question without looking at the actual data. If the sorting is working here and not there perhaps you need to search a bit.