# plotting a series pie chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, pie-chart

I have a series df2 which I want to plot using pie chart

```
 Index
Friday       2
Thursday     2
Wednesday    3
```

I have tried

```
 colors =  ["#E13F29", "#D69A80", "#D63B59", "#AE5552", "#CB5C3B", "#EB8076", "#96624E"]
df2.plot().pie(df2['counts'],df2.index,shadow=False,colors=colors, explode=(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.15), startangle=90,autopct='%1.1f%%', )
# View the plot drop above
pyplot.axis('equal')
# View the plot
pyplot.tight_layout()
pyplot.show()
```

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Wednesday'

Comment: You have only 5 days specified for exploding, but 7 colours.

Comment: Seen,thanks, it now works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider a `pd.Series` -

```
s

Index
Monday       2
Tuesday      4
Wednesday    5
Thursday     2
Friday       1
Saturday     6
Sunday       3
Name: counts, dtype: int64
```

Now, call `pd.Series.plot.pie` on `counts` column -

```
s.plot.pie(y=df.index,
           shadow=False,
           colors=colors, 
           explode=(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.15, 0, 0),   # exploding 'Friday'
           startangle=90,
           autopct='%1.1f%%')

plt.axis('equal')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Don't call `plot()`! Call `pie` on `plot`.

[image]

---

If you need your index sorted by weekday, make sure to convert it to `pd.Categorical` -

```
cat = ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday', 'Sunday']

df.index = pd.Categorical(df.index, categories=cat, ordered=True)
df = df.sort_index()
```

And then, you can plot as shown above.

Comment: Is there a way to explode automatically the index with the largest count?

Comment: @Bode `z = np.zeros(7); z[s.reset_index()['counts'].idxmax()] = 0.15`, now pass `z` to `explode=...`

Comment: Nice! that's great

Comment: I don't actually have counts as  a column
KeyError: 'counts'

Comment: @Bode `s.reset_index().iloc[:, -1].idxmax()` then? It's just the name of the column that has your counts...

Comment: what can one do when a column has refused to be sorted using sort_values() https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47935681/dataframe-grouping-and-sorting

Comment: @Bode hmm, that's odd. Maybe it's sorted already? Maybe it's a column of strings? Maybe you're not assigning it?

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this:

```
colors =  ["#E13F29", "#D69A80", "#D63B59", "#AE5552", "#CB5C3B", "#EB8076", "#96624E"]
df.groupby(df.Index.dt.strftime('%A'))['Index'].count().plot.pie(figsize=(5,5),colors=colors,
                                                                 explode=(0,0,0,0.1),
                                                                 startangle=90,
                                                                 autopct='%1.1f%%')
```

Output:

[image]